# Error In Tables Display And Alternate Row Colouring Not Applying to Tables After The First Table

Tags: php, mysql, html-table, rows

Please I need your help with the display of a page in my App. The student profile is gathering relevant data for the courses a student have taken over 10 semesters. The queries are working fine, but the display is not displaying as i want it to be. Also the JavaScript alternate row colouring is not applying to all the remaining tables after the first table.  I'm looking to have something of this nature in the page display.

```
                 RAIN SEMESTERS
     Year1  Year2  Year3 Year4   Year5       

          HARMATTARN SEMESTERS 
 Year1   Year2   Year3  Year4   Year5 .
```

This is an example of the PHP that is generating the tables, the remaining 9 tables are identical with varying Years ( 1-5 ) and Semesters: Rain/Harmattan

```
         echo "<div id=\"contentRight\">" ;
             echo "<span class=\"header\">";
  echo "<p><b>Matric Number: $matric_       no</b></p>";
       echo "<p><b>Year: 100 ; Semester:         Hamattarn</b></p>";
           echo "<table class=\"altrowstable\" id=\"alternatecolor\" bgcolor=gold >\n";
                 echo "<tr align=center>\n";
         for ($i=0; $i<$number_cols1; $i++)
                     {
echo "<th>" . mysql_field_name($query1,     $i). "</th>\n";
                     }
                     echo "</tr>\n";
               while ($row = mysql_fetch_row        ($query1))
                    {
                    echo "<tr align=center>\n";
          for ($i=0; $i<$number_cols1; $i++)
                    {
                    echo "<td>";
            if (!isset($row[$i]))
                    {echo "NULL";}
                    else
                    {
                    echo "<b>".$row[$i]."</b>";
                    }
                    echo "</td>\n";
                    }
                    echo "</tr>\n";
                    }
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo"</span>" ;
```

**CSS**

```
 table.altrowstable td {
 border-width: 2px;
 padding: 4px;
 border-style: solid;
 border-color: #a9c6c9;
 }
 .oddrowcolor{
  background-color:#d4e3e5;
  }
  .evenrowcolor{
  background-color:#c3dde0;
  }
```

**WHAT IS CURRENTLY DISPLAYED**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why dont you use jquery to do the alternating, that way your server isn't being bothered by doing something that the client can do.

using jquery [:odd](http://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selector, combined with [addclass()](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/)

```
// Just a quick example.
$('.classSelector:odd').addClass('oddrowcolor');
```

Then you can get rid of the `for()` in the php statement and just echo out the data without custom formatting.

On each `tr`, add a class called `classSelector`

Simply put this just before your closing `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">
    $('.classSelector:odd').addClass('oddrowcolor');
</script>
```

Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/kNGpB/

Comment: Thanks Mike. I dont know JQuery. I'll be glad if you can point me to a JQuery plugin to help me out.
Thank you Sir.

Comment: see my links in my answer, :odd, and addclass() are the links.. I also edited the answer with a direct link to jquery.

Comment: Edited my answer to include a working example at jsfiddle, also included a snippet of how to include a pre-hosted copy of jquery.